# How to die Correctly on Soap::Lite in perl

Tags: perl

I have written a perl script that connects using `Soap::Lite` and collect data from a web-service and update a database. This works well, until the password gets locked out and I get a `server 500 error` which is where my question comes in. How do I let the `Soap::Lite` query `die` when it does not make a successful connection, so it does not continue with the rest of the script?

```
  .....
  my $host   = "hostname";
  my $user   = "user";
  my $pass   = "pass";
     $soap_proxy  = "https://" . $user . ":" . $pass . "@" . $host . ":8090/services/ApiService";
     $uri    = "http://api.config.common.com";

     $client                                    =  new SOAP::Lite
       uri                                           => $uri,
       proxy                                         => $soap_proxy,
       autotype                                      => 0;
  my $soap_respons = $client->getSomething();
  ....
```

I have tried the usual `or die $!` but that does not `die` like other queries do and still continues with the remaining script.

according to the `SOAP::Lite` examples on CPAN, you could use:

```
if ($@) {
   die $@;
 }
```

But I do not know where to put this. I tried directly under `my $soap_respons` but still it does not die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOAP::Lite` queries will give a `fault` with a `faultstring` result if errors occur, something like this should work.

```
die $soap_respons->faultstring if ($soap_respons->fault);
print $soap_respons->result, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `on_fault` callback. This way you wouldn't have to check every response.

```
$client->on_fault(sub { die($_[1]) });
```